# Float formatting: maximum precision but not fixed

Tags: java

I try to format a float number with at most 3 digits, but avoiding the trailing zeros. I use this format string:

```
 %1$,.3f
```

And it correctly formats the number `1000.123` as what I expect: `1.000,123`

But for the float `1000.12`, I get the formatted result `1.000,120` whereas I would like have the trailing zero out, resulting on `1.000,12` instead.

Any idea on what is wrong with my formatting string?

Comment: Are you sure about that pattern yields, `1.000,123` as output for `1000.123` as input ? I got different result.

Comment: @soufrk Note that the format String you presented is not safe when using other Locale than yours. You might want to look at my answer to see that you can change it to cover cases when other locale uses other decimal or grouping separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously this answer had a regex way of dealing with the formatted `String` of `double`/`float`, but it is not a good approach. For formatting `double`/`float`, there is a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class:

```
String formatted = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###").format(1000.120);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

`#,###.###` is equivalent to `%1$,.3f` with the required format: It strips out trailing zero from the output `String`.

`,` is grouping separator, `#` represents absent digit, `.` is decimal separator. So `#,###.###` means that it will format `1000000.190` to `1,000,000.19` and `1000.199` to `1,000.199`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @edutesoy Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but, will you consider this,

```
double[] numbers = {1000.123, 1000.12};
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
            NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
for(double d:numbers)
    System.out.format("%1$,.3f\n", d);
for(double d:numbers)
    System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(d));
```

Seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code locale-independent, you should consider using methods that return *decimal separator* and *grouping separator* used in your system. After formatting that leaves only 3 digits after decimal separator, method `replaceAll()` is called to cut trailing zeros:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
char groupingSeparator = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
char decimalSeparator = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
String s = String.format("%1$"+ groupingSeparator + decimalSeparator + "3f" , floatYouWantToFormat).replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""); // floatYouWantToFormat is, of course, float you want to format to meet your expectations
```